# sequence convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Assume all terms $a(n) >0$ , $\sqrt{a(1)}\geqslant 1 +\sqrt{a(0)}$, and
$$\left|\dfrac{a(n+1)}{a(n)}-\dfrac{a(n)}{a(n-1)}\right|\leqslant \dfrac{1}{a(n)} $$
for all $n>0$.

1. Prove that $\dfrac{a(n+1)}{a(n)}$ is convergent to some $L\geqslant 1$.
2. Prove that $L>1$.
3. Prove that $\dfrac{a(n)}{L^n}$ is convergent.

Comment: sorry but where did L come from?

Comment: It's hiding in the first part: $\displaystyle L = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a(n+1)}{a(n)}$.

Comment: Does "then" actually mean that the condition must hold? Because otherwise, the inequality recurrence is true for the sequence $a(i) = 2^{2^i}$, but none of the rest need to hold.

Comment: Maybe “then” means: For any $n>0$, the inequality holds. (I.e., if $n>0$, then …)

Comment: As @user58811 does not seem interested in clearing up the confusion about the meaning, I have taken the liberty of doing a possibly harmful edit. “In order to save the question, I had to destroy it.” user58811 should change it if I got it wrong.

Comment: To Harald you wrote the correct version.Thank you